# Javascript - async addEventListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to learn/code async Javascript (Chrome extension) and I'm getting two errors.
Can someone please assist?

```
self.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    e.waitUntil(async function () { // Error: Uncaught TypeError: e.waitUntil is not a function
        
        if (e.deltaX == 0 && e.deltaZ == 0) {
            if (e.deltaY > 0)  triggerKeydown(false);
            else if (e.deltaY < 0)  triggerKeydown(true);
        }
        await delay(1000);
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        
        return; 
    });
});

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

2nd Error (it didn't supply a line number):

The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before 'preloadResponse' settled. If
you intend to use 'preloadResponse', use waitUntil() or respondWith() to wait for the promise to
settle.

Comment: waitUntil is not part of a onwheel event. Get rid of that.

Comment: I see, thanks. So how do I run await delay(1000); in a non-async function?

Comment: put the async on the `(e) => {`

Comment: like this?  async  (e) => {

Comment: Don't *just* put the async on the handler no, you'd start **a lot** of such async calls in parallel defying the whole point of your code. What you want is to debounce or throttle your event.

Comment: oh, adding async seemed to work perfectly. If you could post the code on how to do it properly, that would be great as I'm very new to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help *@epascarello*.
It now works by adding: `async (e) => {`